# Rewrite old .aspx path to new MVC path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-rewrite-module

i have a mixed aspx/MVC webapp project and need to rewrite incoming URL's either in the MVC routing or through IIS rewriting. whatever works. I cannot figure this out.

I have the following OLD path:

```
/Article/Nugget/Article.aspx?articleId=30
```

and i need to rewrite this to:

```
/Article/Nugget/30
```

The issue is the MVC route is reading in the Article.aspx being passed as a parameter and anything i do to rewrite this in IIS7 is being ignored. Well.. the issue is i don't have a clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Article",
            "Article.aspx",
            new { controller = "Article", action = "Nugget"}
        );
```

With a parameter named articleId in your action method of course

```
public ActionResult Nugget(int articleId)
{
..
}
```

Comment: anyway to not have to use articleID in the Nugget signature? i'd rather use id if possible..

Comment: this also breaks the route for Article/Nugget/50

Comment: if your parameter is named articleId, your value in the route should match for consistency. The alternative is to also specify an MVC route for /Article/Nugget/{articleId}  there are those that believe all routes should be specified rather than a single one matching everything for a generic parameter named 'id' and I tend to agree.

Comment: actually this doesn't work because the articleID from the old URL is not passed along to the controller. /Article/Nugget/Article.aspx?articleId=30 throws an error of missing parameter articleID based on the route above.. dang

Comment: im not following, this should work fine. You should now have two routes for article one for aspx and one mvc specific for controller/action. The mvc one should specify {articleId}, not {id} - what routes are you using?